# Can you grab or delete between parentheses in vi/vim?

Tags: editor, vim

Given this line of code in C:

> `printf("%3.0f\t%6.1f\n", fahr, ((5.0/9.0) * (fahr-32)));`

Is there a way to delete or yank from the first bold parenthesis to its matching parenthesis? I thought about **df)**, but that only will get you to just after the 9.0.

Is there a similar way to get vim to grab everything between matching braces, regardless of newlines?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

### Various Motions: %

The [`%` command](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#%) jumps to the match of the item under the cursor. Position the cursor on the opening (or closing) paren and use `y%` for yanking or `d%` for deleting everything from the cursor to the matching paren.

This works because `%` is a "motion command", so it can be used anywhere vim expects such a command. From [`:help y`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#y):

```
["x]y{motion}       Yank {motion} text [into register x].  When no
                    characters are to be yanked (e.g., "y0" in column 1),
                    this is an error when 'cpoptions' includes the 'E'
                    flag.
```

By default, "item" includes brackets, braces, parens, C-style comments and various precompiler statements (`#ifdef`, etc.).

There is a plugin for "extended % matching" that you can find on the [Vim homepage](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39).

You can read the documentation on `%` and related motion commands by entering [`:help various-motions`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#various-motions) in command mode.

### object-select

There is another set of motion commands that you can use in Visual mode to select various text objects.

To solve your specific problem you would do the following:

```
printf("%3.0f\t%6.1f\n", fahr, ((5.0/9.0) * (fahr-32)));
                                   ^
```

Let's say your cursor is positioned at `^`. Enter the following sequence to select the part you are looking for:

```
v2a)
```

First `v` enters Visual mode, then you specify that you want to go `2` levels of parens up. Finally the `a)` selects "a block". After that you can use `d` or `x` to delete, etc.

If you don't want to include the outer parens, you can use "inner block" instead:

```
v2i)
```

See [`:help object-select`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#object-select) for the complete list of related commands.

Comment: Thanks! I knew about % switching between matching items; didn't know it was useful within commands as well. +1 and accepted.

Comment: Interesting, I always thought `a` meant "around" rather than "a". Feel like it complements "inner" better. Not a day goes by not learning something new about Vim it seems.

Answer (score 291):

What about **`dib`** or **`di(`**.

It will delete the *inner* (...)  block where the cursor is.

I love [text-object](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#object-select) motions and selections!

Comment: Luckily, this question is the first hit when I google for it – I don’t know how many times this answer has saved me. And I always forget it … :-(

Comment: Is it possible to delete including the parentheses? (yep, I answered my own question: `dab` => delete *a* block (including its parentheses)

Comment: I vote up. Additionally if you want to correct word inside parenthesis do **ciw**.

Comment: +1! I was mind-blown when I discovered text-object motions recently! no more trying to position cursor in the right spot to yank text :D

Answer (score 50):

To delete all that is inside a pair of parentheses, you can always issue `di(` and its derivatives.

**Note :**

As @porglezomb suggested in his comment, you can use `a` ("along with") instead of `i` ("inside") to include the parentheses. So, using `da(` deletes everything inside `(` and `)` including `(` and `)`.

**Deleting text inside the immediate outer pair of parentheses :**

So, for this line of code

```
printf("%3.0f\t%6.1f\n", fahr, ((5.0/9.0) * (fahr-32)));
                                ^       ^
                                |       |
                                 \_______\___---> Cursor range
```

assuming that your cursor is inside the above mentioned cursor range, you can issue the following commands :

```
di(   --> Deletes '5.0/9.0'
ci(   --> Substitutes '5.0/9.0'
yi(   --> Yanks '5.0/9.0'
```

**Deleting text inside the n-th outer pair of parentheses :**

To grab everything inside the n-th outer pair of parentheses, just add `n` before the above command. So, with the same cursor position as above,

```
2di(   --> Deletes '(5.0/9.0) * (fahr-32)'
2ci(   --> Substitutes '(5.0/9.0) * (fahr-32)'
2yi(   --> Yanks '(5.0/9.0) * (fahr-32)'

3di(   --> Deletes '"%3.0f\t%6.1f\n", fahr, ((5.0/9.0) * (fahr-32))'
3ci(   --> Substitutes '"%3.0f\t%6.1f\n", fahr, ((5.0/9.0) * (fahr-32))'
3yi(   --> Yanks '"%3.0f\t%6.1f\n", fahr, ((5.0/9.0) * (fahr-32))'
```

Comment: You should add a note talking about `a` as the counterpart to `i`, since that's likely to help a lot of people.

Comment: @romandas this should be the accepted question. I was searching for the exact same problem today and @Kevin is the only one here giving the proper answer. Of course, I could "misuse" `%` for this problem, but this takes more time and, in my opinion, should only be used for more complex scenarios. Deleting something inside a certain scope is exactly the use-case `di` is made for.

Answer (score 21):

You can use `d%` for deleting and `y%` for yanking.

Comment: % is the movement specifier for "matched parenthesis, bracket, or brace".  Any movement specification can be paired with d and y (and many other things).

Answer (score 11):

Place your cursor on the first parenthesis, then press `v%y` or `v%d`.

Comment: Great! % jumps to the matching paren. So you can even use d% and y%.

Comment: Note, too, that 'd%' can start at the beginning of a function name, and will delete the entire function call.  It also works for '{}', '[]' and even '<>' pairs.

Comment: @Leffler, Thanks for the tips!  And it's good to know % works in visual mode as well.

Answer (score 4):

Try ci[block-surrounder]

In your case, place the cursor anywhere between the 2 parenthesis that you highlighed and try the keys: ci(

Comment: Nearly.  Testing this, it looks like the cursor needs to be on the first parenthesis, not between, and 'c' is the change command.  With the cursor on the opening parenthesis, 'di(' deletes to the matching closing parenthesis, and 'yi(' yanks.

Comment: ci works for me all the time. All I need to do is making sure the cursor is between those parenthesis that surround the block of text I need to delete.

Answer (score 3):

As [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/405420/611007) of David Norman says,

### Place your cursor on the first parenthesis, then press `v%y` or `v%d`.

Explanation from http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/vimindex.html:

```
tag                char           note action in Normal mode        
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|v|                v                   start characterwise Visual mode
|%|                %                1  find the next (curly/square) bracket on
                                       this line and go to its match, or go to
                                       matching comment bracket, or go to matching
|d|                ["x]d{motion}    2  delete Nmove text [into buffer x]
```

This means it will select everything between and including the two brackets (`%`) while showing the selection to you visually (`v`) and then yank/copy `y` or delete/cut `d` it. (To the default buffer.)

You can put/paste with `p`.

Made this answer to ["teach myself to fish"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime).

Comment: note: vimdoc.sourceforge.net is linked from vim.org which is the official site of vim as of 2015.